# Exact ODE: Why is $du = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

The following form

$$M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy$$

can be derived from the total differential of a bivariate function $u(x,y)$, which is

$$du = u_x(x,y)dx + u_y(x,y)dy.$$

Therefore, $du = M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy$.

This is perfectly understandable so far.

Then we somehow set $u(x,y) = c$, which makes the differential of $u$ equal to $0$.

I'm confused about this. If $u(x,y) = c$, then $y$ is no longer an independent variable. The value of $y$ is now dependent on $x$.

Simply put, $u(x,y) = c$ is equal to $u(x,y(x)) = c$. It's really just an implicit form of a single-variable function.

So how is $du$ even defined in this case? Why is $du$ equal to $0$ when there's no tangent plane to approximate the value of $\Delta u$ in the first place?

Comment: Is setting $u(x,y) =c$ an equation that defines some curve, or just sets value of u to c everywhere? If the latter, it makes perfect sense, since you end up with $du = c_x dx + c_y dy = 0dx + 0dy = 0$

Comment: I agree that if $u(x,y)$ is a plane parallel to the xy plane, then $du = 0$ without a doubt. But it seems like $u(x,y) = c$ defines a curve, since it's the solution of the ode.

Comment: $du$ is 0 since  $u_x(x,y )$ and  $u_y(x,y)$ are both $0$, if $u(x,y)=c$. **Important:** If you want to construct a tangent at an arbitrary point you need another linear function. Something like $r\cdot x+s\cdot y=t$

Comment: @callculus The partials don't see dependence between the variables, so there's no reason they should be zero.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I have to admit that don´t know what really the questions is. But independence implies a differential of $0$.  That´s all I can say.

Comment: @callculus For example, if $u(x,y) = 2x - y$ then $u_x=2, u_y=-1$.  On $y=2x$ we have $du = 0$ but we still have $u_x=2, u_y=-1$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks for the reply and your answer below. I think I've understood what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always understood the total differential $$du = M(x,y)\,dx + N(x,y)\,dy$$
in this context to be notational shorthand for
$$\frac{du}{dt} = M(x(t),y(t))\,\frac{dx}{dt} + N(x(t),y(t))\, \frac{dy}{dt}.$$
for any differentiable curve $t \mapsto (x(t),y(t))$.

---

Along this vein, $du=0$ on $u(x,y) = c$ means that for any differentiable curve $t \mapsto (x(t), y(t))$ on $u(x,y)=c$, we have $\frac{d}{dt}u(x(t),y(t)) = 0.$

At this point, it should be obvious.  If $t \mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ is a curve on $u(x,y)=c$, then for all $t$, $u(x(t),y(t))=c$, and the derivative of a constant is zero.

Comment: A little bit of a disclaimer: I didn't go far into mathematical dynamics in my studies and I hardly touched differential geometry, so if my understanding of the total differential is too narrow for this context, tell me and I'll remove it.  However, I don't expect we need to invoke the full framework of differential forms here.

Comment: That clears a lot of things up, I've never looked at it in that perspective, thanks!